# ng-click not firing on checkbox consistently

Tags: angularjs

I've come across a weird issue where ng-click not firing on checkbox all the time.
I have 3 different ul's, they're all the same but display different data (i.e. different ng-repeats and different ng-models)

When I click the checkbox on the element item, it should call a function.

It works on the ALL FILTERS one - the function is always called.

For the other 2, it sometimes works, but most of the time it does not work for the HIDDEN/VISIBLE FILTERS. By sometimes, I mean that I refresh the page and try again, randomly works sometimes. The function is simply not called most of the other times!

HTML Code is:

```
<div class="col-md-4" ng-style="{ 'height' : filtersHeight , 'max-height' : filtersHeight }">
    <!--ALL FILTERS-->
    <ul style="padding-left: 0;" ng-style="{ 'height' : filtersHeight , 'max-height' : filtersHeight }" ng-if="search.filters.visible === undefined" ui-sortable ng-model="customScreen.filters" class="list-formbuilder-sortable-columns">
      THIS IS ALL FILTERS
      <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="filter in customScreen.filters | filter:search.filters" ng-class="{'active':selectedElement.filters.name === filter.name}" ng-click="selectElement(filter,'filters')">
        {{filter.displayName}}
        <div ng-if="!filter.required" class="pull-right">
          <input  ng-disabled="::!isUserEntitled('EDIT')" type="checkbox" value="" ng-model="filter.visible" ng-change="updateFilterArrays(filter)">
        </div>
      </li>
      search: {{search.filters}}
    </ul>
    <!--VISIBLE FILTERS-->
    <ul ng-style="{ 'height' : filtersHeight , 'max-height' : filtersHeight }" ng-if="search.filters.visible === true" ui-sortable ng-model="visibleFilters" class="list-group formbuilder-sortable-columns">
      THIS IS ONLY VISIBLE FILTERS
      <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="filter in visibleFilters | filter:search.filters" ng-class="{'active':selectedElement.filters.name === filter.name}" ng-click="selectElement(filter,'filters')">
        {{filter.displayName}}
        <div ng-if="!filter.required" class="pull-right">
          <input  ng-disabled="::!isUserEntitled('EDIT')" type="checkbox" value="" ng-model="filter.visible" ng-change="updateFilterArrays(filter)">
        </div>
      </li>
      visibleFilters: {{visibleFilters}} <br/>
      search: {{search.filters}}<br/><br/><br/>
      customScreen.filters: {{customScreen.filters}}
    </ul>
    <!--HIDDEN FILTERS-->
    <ul ng-style="{ 'height' : filtersHeight , 'max-height' : filtersHeight }" ng-if="search.filters.visible === false" ui-sortable ng-model="hiddenFilters" class="list-group formbuilder-sortable-columns">
      THIS IS ONLY HIDDEN FILTERS
      <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="filter in hiddenFilters | filter:search.filters" ng-class="{'active':selectedElement.filters.name === filter.name}" ng-click="selectElement(filter,'filters')">
        {{filter.displayName}}
        <div ng-if="!filter.required" class="pull-right">
          <input  ng-disabled="::!isUserEntitled('EDIT')" type="checkbox" value="" ng-model="filter.visible" ng-change="updateFilterArrays(filter)">
        </div>
      </li>
      hiddenFilters: {{hiddenFilters}} <br/>
      search: {{search.filters}}<br/><br/><br/>
      customScreen.filters: {{customScreen.filters}}

    </ul>
  </div>
```

Note I have another checkbox which does the same (there's one in the row, and one in another panel)

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="checkbox col-md-12" style="margin-left: 15px;">
        <label>
          <input ng-disabled="::!isUserEntitled('EDIT')" type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedElement.filters.visible" ng-disabled="selectedElement.filters.required" ng-change="updateFilterArrays(selectedElement.filters)"/> Show Filter
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Likewise this one is ALWAYS called.

The solution is to use ng-change instead, but I'm wondering if anyone can tell me why ng-click on checkbox doesn't seem to always fire for above case please?

Comment: does `ng-chage` worked for you? I think because of `ng-if` you need to use `$parent.selectElement(filter,'filters')`

Answer (score 0):

1. In your example, you have 2x ng-disabled
2. use only ng-model="" on your checkbox
3. use watcher to trigger some functionality after your filter change

```html
$scope.$watch('selectedElement.filters', function(newValue) {
    // do some stuff with selectedElement.filters via "newValue" object/array
    // angular.forEach(newValue, function(value,key) {......}); or so...
}, true); // TRUE for object equality check, refer scope.$watch reference
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Comment: Good spot about the ng-disabled, thanks. It still works this way it seems, but I will clean it up.

Using ng-change makes it work fine so I don't need to use a watcher - I am just wondering why it doesn't play properly the way it is. But thanks anyway!

Comment: ok, so, maybe <li ng-click> is colliding with click on checkbox?  try to add stopPropagation to li.ng-click <li ng-click="selectElement(filter,'filters'); $event.stopPropagation();"> to prevent "double click" on checkbox and LI. If that selectElement do similar/same thing, they can toggle.